# Oracle PL/SQL: How to return a string value based on an ID field for the same record?

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

Being new to PL/SQL, I want to write a simple function that returns a string value when I input its associate ID value (that is, input one field and return another field associated with the same record). For example, in a table with addresses and associated IDs, if I pass '100' (no quotes) into the function, '350 Pearl St' is returned.

So far I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_term
    (MAJOR_ID_IN IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT t.TERM_NAME
    FROM CV_RELATION r, CV_TERMS t
    WHERE t.TERM_ID = r.MAJOR_ID_IN; --Primary Key linked to Foreign Key
END get_term;
```

This returns a list; however, I want the string name so I can use it in other functions to return success messages, instead of returning the somewhat-cryptic IDs (e.g., 'You've successfully updated address 350 Pearl St' vs. 'You've successfully updated address 100'). Do note that I am calling the ID from a Foreign Key in another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

I added a return variable.  I then selected INTO the variable.  I then returned the variable at the end.  I also removed the extraneous table.  You were not joining with that table so were going to suffer with a cartesian join, but it was not needed anyway since the input variable was the key you needed.

Now, this is actually going to be insufficient.  Using SELECT .. INTO works well when there is one and only one row returned.  If no row is returned, exception.  You can fix this by catching this exception and defaulting your return value.  If >1 rows are return, exception.  You can fix this by making sure the query is limited to return no more than one row, like with FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY (available with 12c).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_term
    (MAJOR_ID_IN IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    ret_val cv_terms.term_name%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT t.TERM_NAME
    into ret_val
    FROM CV_TERMS t
    WHERE t.TERM_ID = MAJOR_ID_IN; --Primary Key linked to Foreign Key

    return ret_val;
END get_term;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I didn't add the exceptions (NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY_ROWS) for the sake of simplicity and irrelevance at the time, but I will catch them. Marked as correct.

Comment: +1 for anchoring the data type of the return variable. (Will that potentially cause an issue, though, since the return data type is declared `varchar2` but the variable is of anchored data type? In this case it won't matter because the anchored type **is** `varchar2`.) The +1 is also for discussing potential exceptions. Nice work!

Comment: @mathguy       the anchored type will always be varchar2 due to its definition in the cv_terms table. I would also +1 you, Duke, but I can't yet. :) Thanks again.